# Gradle failOnVersionConflict only if forcedModules is empty

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

is there a way to specify that I want Gradle's conflict resolution to fail on conflict, but only when I did NOT specify some forced modules ?

Let's say `groupe:module` has a transitive dependency with `groupe:module1`

example1:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'group:module:version'
  compile ('groupe:module1:version1') {
    force = true
  }
}
```

In this case, I do NOT want to fail if there is a conflict between dependencies.
(Because I consider that I know what I do when I force module1 to be at `version1`. I know that other higher dependencies will be taken from `version1`, even if they conflict with the default `version`)

example2:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'group:module:version'
}
```

In this case, if there are some conflicts between second level dependencies, I want to be notified (because this is not supposed to happen in my dependencies trees)

I tried something like :

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        if ( forcedModules.isEmpty() ){
            failOnVersionConflict()
        }
    }
}
```

but (as I feared) I did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you force module versions with `resolutionStrategy.force`, you'll get this behavior out-of-the-box. If you must force as part of declaring the dependency, you may have to iterate over all of the configuration's `ExternalDependency`s and check if any of them has `force` set to `true`.